# Cannot find variable application error

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, declarative

How to get application attribute in declarative? I used this code, but it is not working.

```
<%!
     TestValues tvtemp = TestValues application.getAttribute("tv1");
%>
```

Error details:

```
    PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
    cannot find symbol
    symbol:   variable application
```

Comment: why do you think that this will work.why there is a space between **TestValues** and **application.getAttribute("tv1");**

Comment: Please try importing the TestValues Class on that jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to cast the `getAttribute()` values to the `TestValues` class . import it on the jsp you are using it and syntax should be ,

```
 <%!    
    TestValues tvtemp = (TestValues) application.getAttribute("tv1");
  %>
```

However `srcriplets` are discouraged over the decades and should be avoided . You can use the jstl and el .

Read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)